# Send multiple transactions

Tags: contract-development, tokens

This is contract I plan to implement multi send, so I can send multiple transactions to people. Here is my code

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

/**
 * @title Ownable
 * @dev The Ownable contract has an owner address, and provides basic authorization control 
 * functions, this simplifies the implementation of "user permissions". 
 */
contract Ownable {
  address public owner;

  function Ownable() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier onlyOwner() {
    if (msg.sender != owner) {
      revert();
    }
    _;
  }

  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
    if (newOwner != address(0)) {
      owner = newOwner;
    }
  }

}

contract ERC20Basic {
  uint public totalSupply;
  function balanceOf(address who) constant returns (uint);
  function transfer(address to, uint value);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
}

contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) constant returns (uint);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value);
  function approve(address spender, uint value);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}

contract Airdropper is Ownable {

    function multisend(address _tokenAddr, address[] dests, uint256[] values)
    onlyOwner
    returns (uint256) {
        uint256 i = 0;
        while (i < dests.length) {
           ERC20(_tokenAddr).transfer(dests[i], values[i]);
           i += 1;
        }
        return(i);
    }
}
```

Is it going to work if I deploy this, is it really going to take tokens from my account to be able to distribute to different addresses?

This is my original contract: https://bitbucket.org/trbsi/ethcontract

Answer (score 1):

That contract will send tokens assigned to the contract to multiple recipients.

To send your tokens to multiple addresses, first you have to send your tokens to the contract, and then call multisend in the contract.